# After switching to ESM import in .ts files no longer supports files without extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, esmodules

After switching from CommonJS to esnext module, import of other .ts files from .ts file is no longer possible.

My getButton.ts imports this:

```
import { Button } from "../../../objects/Button";
```

ts.config:

```
{
    "extends": "..",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "types": [
              ....
        ],
        "target": "esnext"
    },
}
```

package.json has:

```
"type": "module"
```

So now when I try to run this, I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module /../../Button
...
 at ESMLoader.resolve
```

When I provide the full path with .ts extension, I get:

```
An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.
```

I would like to avoid adding .ts extension to all files, since it cause many other errors to appear, is it possible to solve this by some other way?

Comment: _"no longer supports files without extension"_ - that's not what the last error says. Please make sure the file is in the correct place?

Comment: Last error happens after I provide .ts extension, only way to make it work without errors is to give .js extension of the actual .ts file, but I am not sure if that solution is good, has some limitations? 

As mentioned, is there a way to keep files without extension?

Answer (score -1):

In literally says
An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension **when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled**.

Disable 'allowImportingTsExtensions' in tsconfig.json

Comment: But I do not have 'allowImportingTsExtensions' in my tsconfig.json. 
After adding it many other errors appear.